# webserver not access from browser

Tags: phpmyadmin, wamp

can't access phpMyAdmin on remote not access from browser.
My wampserver version is 3.0.6 using windows server 2008 R2 64 bit.

localhost/phpmyadmin/ ---> it's OK but if mywebsite.it/phpmyadmin ---> KO

when i open it. Why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default all of WAMPServer is configured to be accessed only from the PC running WAMPServer, this is to protect those that dont yet know what they are doing from the dangers of allowing access from another PC let alone the whole internet.

`phpMyAdmin` is protected in the Alias definition that is used to make `phpMyAdmin` work.

So to open this up to outside access you edit `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`

It looks like this by default, *Your version of `phpMyAdmin` may be different to this example*

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "D:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.1/"

<Directory "D:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.7.1/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
  </ifDefine>

  <ifDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
  </ifDefine>

# To import big file you can increase values
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

As you are using WAMPServer 3, you will be using Apache2.4 so you need to amend this section only

```
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
  </ifDefine>
```

Avoid using `Require all granted` unless you really want the universe to be able to delete your databases.

So to allow others on your network to see Apache do

```
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1
  </ifDefine>
```

Here I am assuming you are on a subnet starting with `192.168.1` you should amend that to the actual subnet you are on.

If you only want specific ip addresses to be able to access `phpMyAdmin` then do this for example

```
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require local
        Require ip 192.168.1.100
        Require ip 192.168.1.101
        Require ip 192.168.1.102
  </ifDefine>
```

If you want to allow the universe into your `phpMyAdmin` then do

```
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        Require all granted
  </ifDefine>
```

But make sure your `root` account in MySQL has a very secure password first, and **definitely make sure it is not left without a password at all**.

Once you have amended this file, restart Apache so it picks up the changes.